# Java IF ELSE syntax error

Tags: java

I'm having a java syntax error on IF ELSE statement. 
I reviewed my code several times but couldn't figure out what's wrong.
The Error is : Syntax error on token "else", delete this token. 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
if(androidFragment!=null)
    ft.detach(androidFragment);

if(appleFragment!=null)
    ft.detach(appleFragment);

if(berryFragment!=null)
    ft.detach(berryFragment);


if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("android")){

    if(androidFragment==null){      

        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AndroidFragment(), "android");                       
    }else{

        ft.attach(androidFragment);                     
    }

}else if{   

    if(appleFragment==null){

        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AppleFragment(), "apple");                       
    }else{

        ft.attach(appleFragment);               
    }

}else{  

    if(berryFragment==null){

        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new BerryFragment(), "berry");                       
    }else{

        ft.attach(berryFragment);                       
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Use the auto-format command of your IDE,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `else` attached to an `if`; here you have two `else`s, for `AppleFragment` and `BerryFragment`.

```
if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("android")){

  ...
}else{  

    ...

}else{  

    ...

}
```

**EDIT**

You now have the following code fragment:

```
} else if {
```

Your `else if` requires a condition, e.g.

```
} else if (/*another boolean condition here for AppleFragment*/) {
```

Comment: I saw your question edit.  I have edited my answer; you need a condition on your `else if`.

Comment: @Downvoter - The OP _originally_ had `} else {` but later changed it to `} else if {`.  If that's not the reason, then why did you downvote?

Answer (score 3):

You have no condition in this `if`

```
...
}else if{ /* condition missing at this if */  

    if(appleFragment==null){

        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AppleFragment(), "apple");                       
    }else{

        ft.attach(appleFragment);               
    }
}...
```

Change it to what you need, possibly:

```
...
}else if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")){

    if(appleFragment==null){

        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AppleFragment(), "apple");                       
    }else{

        ft.attach(appleFragment);               
    }
}...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to your problem.  Please accept it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 else's in a row

```
if (...) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
} else {   <--only one "else" allowed.
   ...
}
```

Comment: He has an 'if' after the first else.  His issue isn't the two elses, but rather the 'if' having no condition.

Comment: I was wondering if the post had been edited, but I saw no evidence of it.  Nor did I know you even could edit your post without a "Last Editted" stamp appearing on it.

Comment: there's a period where the edit flag doesn't come up. not sure what it is, but it lets the question be updated without counting as an edit.

Comment: @MarcB Fix your answer. Don't just leave it like that.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the `else if` construct properly, you code should look like :

```
}else if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {   

    if(appleFragment==null){
        ...

}else if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("berry")){  

    if(berryFragment==null){
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one else is allowed, use else if

```
if(condition){ ....

}else if(condition 2){ ......

}else{ ........

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
else{   // Second else compilation error

    if(berryFragment==null){

        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new BerryFragment(), "berry");                       
    }else{

        ft.attach(berryFragment);                       
    }

}
```

You cannot have two else statements.